# Quartz composer/Origami: how to add a conditional logic

Tags: logic, conditional-statements, quartz-composer, origami

I would like to make an different animation depending if the switch is off or on.

Let say if my switch is ON my sprite move x +10
if my switch is OFF my sprite move y +10

I don't find a correct way to apply it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use one out of three PatchTrees with a simple logic.
The first one works like this: after pressing LMB, your sprite translates 0.1 along +X. After releasing LMB sprite returns to its default position (0). The same thing happens with pressing and releasing RMB (Y+0.1).

[image]

The second scheme uses slightly different logic: clicking LMB you translate your sprite X+0.1 and clicking RMB you translate your sprite Y+0.1. This logic can be accomplished if you use "Counter" patch (with "Reset" parameter).

Remember! your QC's default XY grid ranges from -1 to +1 for X and Y (totally 2 for each axis).

[image]

The third one is a switcher based on a formula of inversion: **abs(a-b)**.
*b=1*. I used patch named "Mathematical expression". This PatchTree is made just for one input (LMB for instance). Maybe third scheme is what you are looking for.

Logic is simple:

```
if a = 0  ->  abs(0-1)  ->  abs(-1) = 1
```

...

```
if a = 1  ->  abs(1-1)  ->  abs(0) = 0
```

[image]